# Font Awesome Icons not showing up

Tags: font-awesome

I'm trying to use some Font Awesome Icons in my nav. Just some simple down arrows next to each list item. If I hotlink to the Font Awesome CDN, it works fine, Whenever I try to copy the files locally and upload them to my server, I just get the square boxes. I'm pretty sure all my paths are correct, just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

http://builderpreviews22.com/

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sass or scss, make sure that the path to the font library is relative to the compiled css file and not the _variables.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

A **network error 500** in your site:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://builderpreviews22.com/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3"
```

This happens when the browser tried to load an inexistent content, in this case the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`.

You have a property in your CSS that gets the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf?=4.0.3` file:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3')
```

Check if you have that file inside your `font-awesome` folder.

Comment: I've checked and double-checked. Everything is there. I'm thinking it might be some kind of problem with my server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nop dude, is really your fault, cause the files should be in `ROOT/common/fonts/`... Did you checked there?

Answer (score 0):

This is also happens to me in my MVC project when deployed to production.

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
```

change it to

```
src: url('../../Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Registering the mime types in your web.config is not enough. Actually the solution is dumb:
After registering the mime types in **web.config** the application will look for **.woff** and **.eot** files extensions. The files extension in your case are actually **.eot?v=4.0.3**. Just rename the files to be **.eot** and **.woff** and replace their includes in other css files by removing the version and it will work like charm :D :)

Answer (score 0):

If all your paths are correct make sure your static files server has CORS enabled and sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  Hope that helps somebody!